# Temporarily launch dhcp server for point to point ethernet connection

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhcpcd

I have a headless computer configured to use a dhcp client which is directly connected to my laptop using an ethernet cable. I'm virtually sure I have seen a one liner before (using dnsmasq?) which would enable me to launch a dhcp server on that interface on my laptop, so that the headless computer would connect to it. This oneliner kept running in the foreground and displayed dhcp requests, so that I would see when the headless computer connected and would know its ip address. Could you tell me what that oneliner is?

I tried searching for quick/temporary dns setups and skimmed dnsmasq's manpage, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: `dnsmasq` can do this. The man page (and the sample configuration file) should show you the necessary command line options

Comment: which OS is the headless computer running?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Debian, but in principle I would prefer a general method. Still haven't had much time to tinker with this, I'll try your suggestions more thoroughly in the next few days and report back, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to it using a local link IPv6 address.

Find out the address of the headless computer (let's say connected to `eth3`) with:

```
$ ping6 -L -I eth3 ff02::1
64 bytes from fe80::2671:89ff:ddb9:80be%eth3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.123 ms
```

Then use the address to `ssh` into it (if `ssh` is enabled).

```
ssh user@[fe80::2671:89ff:ddb9:80be%eth3]
```

Note that those addresses need to have the device attached to them and not all programs can parse them, but `ssh`, for example, can.

If both computers have `avahi-daemon` or a similar mDNS/DNS-SD software, the following command might be enough to connect via `ssh`.

```
ssh user@name_headless.local
```

(you can check with `ping name_headless.local` to see if it is resolving ok).

No need to configure anything else unless, of course, you need IPv4 connectivity.

Comment: That would work in principle, but I couldn't get it to work. In that ssh-command, the ipv6 address is the address of the local computer as returned by ip address show, right?

Comment: No, it is the address of the headless computer, I'm assuming you can access it in non-headless mode just once.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. Is that address permanent? I can get it, but it's a little more work than I thought it should be.

Comment: In my experience it is permanent. But I ended up installing `avahi-daemon` and using the `.local` domain.

Comment: @Nobody this might be an easier way to find out the IPv6 local link address from the other side (a "global" ping on the interface, make sure it is UP): `$ ping6 -I INTERFACE ff02::1` I might change the answer to leave just that, if it works for your.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. In principle I thought arp should be another alternative at least for ipv4, but somehow I got empty results. Maybe the problem is somewhere else entirely.

Comment: When I do that ping command I get replies from localhost and no others... (I went as far as ssh-ing to localhost before I noticed). The interface says it's "state UP", but I'm starting to doubt that.

Comment: I couldn't update the comment, in the answer the command is right: `ping6 -L -I eth3 ff02::1`. You should not get the answers from localhost with `-L`. Check again, because the addresses look very much alike. If you don't get an answer then the other end did not bring up the interface ... but that would be weird.

Answer (score 2):

`dnsmasq --port 0 --no-daemon` will launch `dnsmasq` in the foreground (so that you can see leases being allocated), as a DHCP server only (`--port 0` disables DNS). `dnsmasq` will use the configuration in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`; to ignore it and use default settings add `--conf-file ''`. You may also wish to add `--interface` to prevent `dnsmasq` from binding to all available interfaces by default. See the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dnsmasq) for the full list of options.

Comment: Hmm, I actually tried a very similar command and thought I must have it wrong because it didn't work (other pc didn't connect or at least I didn't see any leases being offered on stdout). In that case I probably didn't set up the connection properly, although I don't know what I could have done wrong, I just used the gnome network manager to set up a static ip of 192.168.20.1 on that interface.